# Getting "Arguments must be aggregate pipeline operators" error in mongoose Node.js

Tags: reactjs, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I am trying to work on my first project using the MERN stack. I have a get request that is trying to return the sum of the all the "cost" fields in my units collection in MongoDB. I am sure i am doing something wrong but after extensive googling I couldn't find anything that made it more clear for me.

I have tried watching some videos and messing with syntax but I am feeling very lost.

```
app.get("/unitsTotal", async (request, response) => {
  try {
    Unit.aggregate([
      {
        $lookup: {
          from: "units",
          localField: "cost",
          foreignField: "_id",
          as: "costs",
        },
        $group: {
          _id: "null",
          totalCost: {
            $sum: "costs",
          },
        },
      },
    ]);
    return response.status(200).json(totalCost);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error.message);
    response.status(500).send({ message: error.message });
  }
});
```

Comment: Is `Unit` a different collection from `"units"`? Can you show a sample document of each collection?

Answer (score 1):

Each stage of the MongoDB aggregation pipeline must be an item of the array, containing a *single* aggregation operator:

```js
Unit.aggregate([
  // 1st stage
  {
    $lookup: { // 1 operator per stage
      // ...
    },
  }, // Notice that each stage is an item (object) of the array, with a single operator (key of the object)

  // 2nd stage
  {
    $group: { // 1 operator per stage
      // ...
    },
  },
]);
```

---

> return the sum of the all the "cost" fields in my units collection in MongoDB

Sounds like you actually involve a single collection here, and you just want to sum *all* documents?

In that case, you do not need  the `$lookup` stage, you can directly `$group` all your documents:

```js
Unit.aggregate([
  {
    $group: {
      _id: null,
      totalCost: {
        $sum: "$cost" // The field path must start with dollar sign "$"
      }
    },
  },
]);
```

[Field path](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/core/aggregation-pipeline/#field-paths) doc:

> To specify a field path, prefix the field name or the dotted field name (if the field is in the embedded document) with a dollar sign `$`. For example, `"$user"` to specify the field path for the `user` field or `"$user.name"` to specify the field path to `"user.name"` field.